# can I get graphics from panel of one jframe to another jframe? (Netbeans)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paint

I am working at symbolic derivatives of concrete functions. I have three classes.

**fnc.java** represnets how to looks like derivatives individual functions. For example:

```
 public void der_cotg(Graphics g,int x, int y){
    drawBroken_line(g,"-1","sin  (x)",x+23,y); //putting pixels between x and y
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD,18));//Graphics g
    g.drawString("2", x+66, y+18);
}
```

**Jmain.java** is JFrame form, represents field, where we can see vizualization of derivatives functions. There are two labels

- f(x) =
- g(x) =            ,

two panels next to them

and button that opens antother JFrame **choose.java** where you can choose function. It is consists of Jpanel and buttons(which represents concrete function) If you press one of theese button, concrete function will be shown at **choose.java** 's Panel.

I want to get Graphics from **choose.java** and set **Jmain.java** 's Panel.
I know how to get and set textfields, but I have not found if it is possible with Panels.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362278/how-to-paint-specific-coordinates-of-one-jpanel-onto-another-jpanel), You can create a `BufferedImage` of the `JPanel` contents. The example has `PanelOne` (which is a `JPanel`) being passed to a method of another `JPanel` (`PanelTwo`), and this is the method in `PanelTwo` that creates a `BufferedImage` from the `PanelOne` passed to it.

```
BufferedImage bi;
....
private void setImage(PanelOne panel) {
    Dimension d = panel.getPreferredSize();
    int w = (int)d.getWidth();
    int h =(int)d.getHeight();
    bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
    panel.paint(g);
    g.dispose();
}
....
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, 250, 250, 0, 0, 250, 250, this);
}
```

Here's the result. `PanelOne` is the left and passes itself to `PanelTwo` on the right

[image]